# If Statement and while loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm a self taught programmer, and I just started using python. I'm having a bit of a problem, when I execute this code:

```
x = 0
while x == 0:
  question = raw_input("Would you like a hint? ")
  if question == "y" or "yes":
    print "Ok"
    first.give_hint("Look over there")
    x = 1
  elif question == "n" or "no":
    print "Ok"
    x = 1
  else:
    print "I'm Sorry, I don't understand that"
```

just so you know, `first.give_hint("Look over there")` was defined in a class earlier in the program, I just left that part out for sake of space. When I run the program no matter what I type, I get the first case "Look over There", I've been trying to figure out what the problem is, but I just don't understand. If you guys could help me, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: In addition to the answers, you might also consider `if question.lower() in ["y", "yes"]:`

Comment: Yes, that's the 'bullet proof' way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if question == "y" or "yes":
```

`"yes"` will always evaluate to `True`.

What you really want is:

```
if question == "y" or question == "yes":
```

Similar changes must be made for the other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your if statement, this should be :

```
if (question == "y") or (question == "yes"):
    print "Ok"
```

Explanation :

```
(question == "y" or "yes")
```

is equivalent to :

```
(question == "y" or "yes" != 0)    # operator 'or' having the prevalence
```

"yes" string being non-null, `("yes" != 0)` always return True, and so do your whole original condition.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is wrong. You have `question == "y"` and a logical `or` with the string `"yes"` that is always `True`. That is why it evaluates to the first case every time.

Try to change to `if question[0] == 'y'`